# Implementations of `CachedRowSet` for Java JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

In Java [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), the [`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html) interface extends from [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

The [`CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) interface extending `RowSet` provides for disconnected use, with data cached in memory, not needing a database connection to be kept open.

[image]

These are interfaces, not implementations.

My question is:

➥ Where do I obtain an implementation of `CachedRowSet`?

I have read that Oracle provides an open-source implementation, but I have not been able to find it.

The `RowSet` Javadoc mentions that [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) vendors may provide an implementation.

Is there an implementation I could use with [*Postgres*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), [*H2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), or [*Microsoft SQL Server*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database servers?

Price is not important. Open source would be nice. Support for [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later is required.

Comment: Are you asking for a library? Just wondering, as asking for [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185) etc. would be off-topic.

Comment: @Izzy I am looking for a class or JAR containing an implementation of `CachedRowSet` interface.

Comment: So it's rather a library to directly use with your code (JARs are usually libraries IIRC), and not code to check how to implement it, right?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, a library. As I mentioned in the Question, some JDBC drivers supposedly may contain an implementation, but I've not seen one. Open-source would be nice but not required.